# Sentence Grammar - Object Problems

Tags: grammar

My friend is a grammar enthusiast.

He has a particular problem with this sentence.

> Waze lets you allow, avoid, or avoid long stretches of unpaved roads.

Please correct and suggest a fix.

There are three options for this particular setting in Waze.

Unpaved roads - Allow, Avoid, Avoid Long Stretches

The intent is to combine:

Waze lets you allow unpaved roads.

Waze lets you avoid unpaved roads.

Waze lets you avoid long stretches of unpaved roads.

Gracias

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: The original was more comical.

Comment: You should listen to your friend. This is confusing word salad to everyone who hasn't spent the last 6 months programming it.

Comment: While I don't disagree that it is confusing, the friend's particular problem is with the use of "allow, avoid, or avoid long stretches of unpaved roads."

Can you combine those three options into one sentence since the first two options refer to unpaved roads and the third refers to long stretches of unpaved roads?  (not saying you should, but is it wrong?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - *Waze lets you allow, avoid, or avoid long stretches of unpaved roads.*

The problem with this sentence starts with the context-freeness of *Waze*, which we discover from later context is evidently a brand name of some route-planning software. That's work enough for the poor reader already.

But then there's the lexical choices: *allow* comes first, again context-free -- what's being allowed here? -- then *avoid*, which begins to look like a binary opposition of objectless transitive verbs, but this is spoiled by repeating *avoid*, this time with a specified direct object.

After more parsing work, the poor reader concludes that one can avoid either all unpaved roads or only some, i.e, long stretches of, unpaved roads. That is a very complex construction, most of which is deleted. Not ideal for business communication.

Most of this must take place before the reader finds out what it is that *Waze* lets you allow or avoid some or all parts of: namely, ***unpaved roads***, the actual topic of the sentence, which appears only at the very end. It should be up front to contextualize the verbs and their ambiguous quantifications.

I would suggest

- *Waze lets you either include or avoid all unpaved roads, or only avoid long stretches of them.*

to take in all the options without adding undue length.

Answer (score 1):

"Lets you allow" doesn't make much sense since "let" and "allow" are pretty much synonymous.

> With Waze, you can use or avoid unpaved roads of any length.

Comment: Good point. _Use_ is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

> Waze lets you allow, avoid, or avoid long stretches of unpaved roads.

The matrix verb is let, which in this context means to 'make something possible through action or inaction,' specifically in this sentence: *the subject makes something possible*, specifically to allow somethings or not allow (avoid) them. So, in this use *the subject **lets** (allows, facilitates, permits) someone or something (required object) to do something (required object complement).* ***Waze lets you*** do something. *Let* requires a direct object (you) and is (always?) followed by a bare infinitive clause (functioning as a required secondary clausal object complement). The verbs *allow* and *avoid* (finite or not) require a noun phrase complement to complete their meaning. We always *allow/avoid* something. But their object (unpaved roads) is buried in the prepositional phrase of another subordinate clause, which means both are syntactically without a required complementary phrase, and hence ungrammatical (by my lights anyway). Perhaps the best remedy for this is to restructure the sentence as follows:

> Waze let's you allow or avoid unpaved roads, or long stretches of
>   them.

Even better:

> Waze let's you use or avoid unpaved roads, or long stretches of them.

I say best because it is still close to the original vocabulary and syntax, but there are lots of other ways to get at the intended meaning as other comments and answers have indicated. Also, the sentence is taken out of context, which makes its interpretation more challenging, but I'm not saying that context could ameliorate the problem of missing verb objects.

Comment: That form suggests there are four options: allow all, avoid all, allow long stretches, avoid long stretches; so it seems to have changed the meaning.

Comment: @JamesRandom : I suppose so, but the original sentence left the verbs in the first clause without a clear object and therefore without complete meaning, right? And anyway, if one can allow all unpaved roads, then one can allow long stretches of them.